# Cardinality of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Problem: Find the number of elements of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Here is my solution: We have already known the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{2^2} , \sqrt{2} \sqrt[3]{2^2} \}$.

Let $f \in G(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}) / \mathbb{Q})$, which means $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2, \sqrt[3]{2})$. We have $f(x) = x, \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(y) \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}), \forall y \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$.

$\forall a \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$, $\exists a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6 \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfied $$a=a_0 + a_1 \sqrt{2} + a_2 \sqrt[3]{2} + a_3 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[3]{2} + a_4 \sqrt[3]{2^2} + a_5 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[3]{2^2}$$

Thus $$f(a) = a_0 + a_1 f(\sqrt{2}) + a_2 f(\sqrt[3]{2}) + a_3 f(\sqrt{2}) f(\sqrt[3]{2}) + a_4 f(\sqrt[3]{2})^2 + a_5 f(\sqrt{2}) f(\sqrt[3]{2})^2.$$

We only need to calculate for $f(\sqrt{2})$ and $f(\sqrt[3]{2})$. As $\sqrt{2}$ is a root of $x^2-2$, $f(\sqrt{2})$ is also a root of $x^2-2$, which means it can be $\sqrt{2}$ or $-\sqrt{2}$. Now, $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is a root of $x^3-2$. So $f(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a root of $x^3-2$. ***In fact $x^3-2 = 0$ has a real solution $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and two complex solutions $x=-\frac{1}{2^{2 / 3}} \pm \frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2^{2 / 3}}$. But $f(\sqrt[3]{2}) \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$. So $f(\sqrt[3]{2})$ cannot be one of the complex solutions, which means $f(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \sqrt[3]{2}$.***

Thus, we only need to consider two different case of $f(\sqrt{2})$ and with some  calculating, we conclude that $|G(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2}))| = 2$.

My question is: Is the step I concluded that $f(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \sqrt[3]{2}$ true (the one in bold and italic)? Is there a more general way to calculate the number of Galois group $G(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)/ \mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: This field extension is not Galois (e.g. not normal since $x^3-2$ does not split into linear factors). But your calculation of $Aut(\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt[3] 2)/\mathbb Q)=\mathbb Z/2$ looks good.